# Easy software to simulate network (router/switch/server) for study purposes

Tags: osx, networking, simulation

I am studying networking, I am looking for a software for Mac for testing.

It must allow me to create a router, switch, and server.

---

**EDIT-01**

Is there a software for testing Juniper devices?

Comment: Do you mean connecting physical Juniper devices for testing or software appliances?

Answer (score 2):

Download and install VirtualBox.

Download a Ubuntu ISO, and install that in a VM.

In your Ubuntu VM, download, install, and run [Cisco Packet Tracer](https://www.netacad.com/courses/packet-tracer).  It is the gold standard for teaching routing and router theory.

Replace Ubuntu with Windows if you want, and have a license...

Answer (score 1):

Try [GNS3](https://www.gns3.com/software).

It is a network simulator that can do what you need and runs on [Mac](https://docs.gns3.com/1MlG-VjkfQVEDVwGMxE3sJ15eU2KTDsktnZZH8HSR-IQ/index.html).

This [intro](https://docs.gns3.com/1wr2j2jEfX6ihyzpXzC23wQ8ymHzID4K3Hn99-qqshfg/index.html) should get you start on building a simulation.

For Juniper, you can [import the vm](http://docs.gns3.com/144QvvLxBT69_fv-pPHf4etc5xjdItiA_a8s8gVmSTDk/index.html).